# Accuracy of Google maps/HERE maps

Tags: latitude-longitude, accuracy

According to this article in https://junipersys.com/support/article/6614, I have a basic understanding of the accuracy of GPS data.

Through calling Google Maps/HERE Maps API, we are able to receive the geo-location information of a point (latitude, longitude and accuracy), then we can make a conclusion that the probability of the true location is within the circle, which is built by the latitude, longitude and accuracy, is xx%.

What is xx for Google Maps and HERE Maps?

Comment: The accuracy is probably not the same for all points, it will vary depending on location and data sources....

Comment: Hi @J.R, thanks for your reply, so how does Google Maps define their accuracy? and how they can guarantee that the true location is within that radius (accuracy)?

Comment: Most devices that use non commercial GPS (like a smartphone) only have an accuracy of  3-10m so your see different results that are dependant on other factors (number of satellites, urban or rural, open sky, vegetation).

Comment: Regardless to whether you're concerned with the browser's [Geolocation API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation_API), or the Google Maps or HERE Maps native library Geolocation APIs, either way, they all interface the same GPS/location sensor/solution, which is probably vendor-specific. So, unless you are asking about the aerial/satellite imagery or the base map data served by those providers, I'm not sure they're relevant to your actual question. i.e. Your concern is with the accuracy of the device-native GPS sensor. No?

Comment: Hi @Mapperz, do you mean that the accuracy is actually depends on the device, is my understanding correct?

Comment: Hi @elrobis, thanks for your reply. So you also mean that the device will decide the accuracy but not Google Maps API/HERE Maps API, am I correct?